# Alternative Python imaging libraries on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-imaging-library

I am thinking about uploading images to Google App Engine, but I need to brighten parts of the image. I am not sure if the App Engine imagine API will be sufficient. I consider to try an overlay with a white image and partial opacity.

However, if that does not yield the desired results, would there be another Python imaging library that works with App Engine? Basically it would have to be pure Python (no associated C code or anything).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PNGcanvas](http://the.taoofmac.com/space/projects/PNGCanvas) might help, if PNG input and output is satisfactory -- it doesn't directly offer the "brighten" functionality you require, but it does let you load and save PNG files into memory and access them directly from Python, and it IS a single, simple Python source file.